# How to use tensorflow metrics Accuracy for multiclass?

Tags: tensorflow

My goal is to understand how tensorflow calculate accuracy.

The problem is, the expected output is `2/3`. Because there are 3 rows, 2 rows correctly predict the label.

```
y_true = np.array([
    [0,1,0,0], # 1st row
    [1,0,0,0], # nth row
    [0,1,0,0],
])
```

The actual output is `0.8333334`.

The code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
m = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
y_true = np.array([
    [0,1,0,0], # 1st row
    [1,0,0,0], # nth row
    [0,1,0,0],
])
y_pred = np.array([
    [0,1,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,0],
])
m.update_state(y_true, 
               y_pred)
m.result().numpy()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are total `12` elements out of which `10` are correct - `10/12 = 0.8333`

What you want is,

```
m.update_state(tf.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), 
               tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1))
#results in 2/3
```

Use, `tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy()` instead

Comment: Thank you for pointing out CategoricalAccuracy, the source code lead me to conclusion that I can do this in the future if I ever need to use different metrics with argmax -> create custom function that accept args y_true and y_pred, and return `tf.metrics.Accuracy( tf.argmax(y_true, axis=-1), tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1) )`